# ¿ como contar el numero de puntos proyectados que caen en cada polígono de un Shapefile usando R?

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

tengo un shapefile del area de Camden de UK el cual se puede descargar aquí (junto con los datos): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Py9BrlB8i0Nz9P_tq92s7Q124iIW-1JQ/view?usp=sharing

hasta el momento cargo las base de datos del Shapefile y luego la base de datos de los puntos y proyecto ambas capas sobre el mismo grafico. esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora.

```
Census.Data <- read.csv("practical_data.csv")

if (!require("rgdal")) install.packages("rgdal")
library("rgdal")
if (!require("rgeos")) install.packages("rgeos")
library("rgeos")

Output.Areas<- readOGR("D:/Camden/shapefiles", "Camden_oa11")
OA.Census <- merge(Output.Areas, Census.Data, by.x="OA11CD", by.y="OA")


houses <- read.csv("camdenhousesales15.csv")

#solo necesito el UID, el precio y las cordenadas. 
houses <- houses[,c(1,2,8,9)]

#lo anterior no tiene atributos espaciales, para poder hacerlo es necesario utilizar el paquete sp. 

if (!require("sp")) install.packages("sp")
library("sp")

#Podemos consultar las referencias en https://spatialreference.org/
houses.points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = houses[,3:4],data = houses,proj4string = CRS("+init=EPSG:27700"))


# Creando un mapa base con la libreria "tmap".
if (!require("tmap")) install.packages("tmap")
library("tmap")

tm_shape(OA.Census) + tm_borders(alpha=.4) +
tm_shape(houses.points) + tm_dots(col = "Price", scale = 2.5, palette = "Reds", style = "quantile", title = "Price Paid (£)")
```

Con lo anterior obtengo el siguiente gráfico.

[image: Puntos sobre el mapa]

Lo que realmente quiero es contar cuantos puntos caen dentro de cada polígono del mapa de Camden y guardar esto como una variable mas en los datos de OA.Census.

he intentado lo siguiente pero sin éxito alguno

```
cuenta <- over(houses.points, OA.Census)
¿¿ count <- as.integer(table(cuenta$id)) ???
```

Comment: Revisa esto de seguro lo puedes ajustar
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133625/checking-if-points-fall-within-polygon-shapefile

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`over()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.4-2/topics/over-methods) pero vas a necesitar que los puntos y lo polígonos tengan la misma proyección:

```
# Heredamos la proyección del shape file
houses.points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = houses[,3:4],
                                        data = houses, 
                                        proj4string = crs(OA.Census))

# Asociamos los puntos con cada polígono
res <- over(houses.points, OA.Census)

# Contamos los puntos por polígono
as.data.frame(table(res$OA11CD))
```

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funcionó esto (para tu ejercicio)

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(tmap)

Census.Data <- read.csv("practical_data.csv")

Output.Areas<- read_sf("Candem_Shapefile/Camden_oa11.shp")

colnames(Output.Areas)[colnames(Output.Areas) == 'OA11CD'] <- 'OA'

OA.Census <- left_join(x = Output.Areas, y = Census.Data, "OA")

houses <- read.csv("camdenhousesales15.csv")

head(houses)

#solo necesito el UID, el precio y las cordenadas. 
houses <- houses[,c(1,2,8,9)]

#lo anterior no tiene atributos espaciales, para poder hacerlo es necesario utilizar el paquete sp. 
require(sp)
#Podemos consultar las referencias en https://spatialreference.org/
houses.points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = houses[,3:4],data = houses,proj4string = CRS("+init=EPSG:27700"))
houses.points <- st_as_sf(houses.points)

tm_shape(OA.Census) + tm_borders(alpha=.4) +
  tm_shape(houses.points) + tm_dots(col = "Price", scale = 2.5, palette = "Reds", style = "quantile", title = "Price Paid (£)")
```

acá realicé este paso para poder contar los puntos en cada poligono:

```
cuenta <- st_intersection(houses.points, OA.Census)
cuenta$n <- 1

cuenta.df <- cuenta %>%
  group_by(OA) %>%
      summarise(sum(n))

> cuenta.df
Simple feature collection with 654 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: GEOMETRY
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 524048 ymin: 181067 xmax: 531511 ymax: 187470
Projected CRS: OSGB36 / British National Grid
# A tibble: 654 × 3
   OA        `sum(n)`                                                       geometry
   <chr>        <dbl>                                                 <GEOMETRY [m]>
 1 E00004120        7                  MULTIPOINT ((526910 184659), (526963 184696))
 2 E00004121        2                                          POINT (527114 184494)
 3 E00004123        1                                          POINT (527102 184157)
 4 E00004124        7 MULTIPOINT ((527415 184906), (527461 184948), (527492 184925))
 5 E00004125        9 MULTIPOINT ((527331 184975), (527373 184973), (527388 185019))
 6 E00004126        7 MULTIPOINT ((526915 184984), (526919 184974), (526971 184982))
 7 E00004127        2                  MULTIPOINT ((527258 185151), (527332 185066))
 8 E00004128        5 MULTIPOINT ((527079 185139), (527090 185100), (527110 185047))
 9 E00004129        3 MULTIPOINT ((527095 184958), (527151 184984), (527215 184972))
10 E00004130        2                  MULTIPOINT ((527176 184931), (527199 184911))
# … with 644 more rows
```

Saludos..